# what is the output number of php strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s")) indicates?

Tags: php

I want to find 15 minutes different between link has sent time and link activated time.For that, I am as below,

```
<?php

$sentTime=strtotime(date("2018-05-29 06:11:42"));
$curTime=strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s"));
$difference=$curTime-$sentTime;

echo $sentTime;
echo '<br>';
echo $curTime;
echo '<br>';
echo $difference;
?>
```

When I do like this it gives some number, 
What is those number indicate?
If it is time, whether is it in minute or seconds or milli seconds?

Can anybody assist me?

Comment: why not you checked the function definition? Php manual made only for this purpose:-[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

The function [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns a timestamp, which is the number of seconds elapsed since Jan 01 1970 (UTC).

`$sentTime`, `$curTime` and `$difference` are seconds.

Answer (score -2):

Please use like this way, its the proper way to declare date

```
  $senttime= date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("2018-05-29 06:11:42"));
```

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't answers OP's question and giving code without explanation isn't welcome on SO and won't help anyone.